# MapBox for Android

Tags: android, mapbox

Помогите решить проблему. В своем проекте я использую MapBox (https://www.mapbox.com). Я создал приложение по этому уроку https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-change-listening/. Но через несколько дней карта перестала отображаться.  Сначала на одном устройстве, затем на другом. Если установить приложение на новое устройство, то приложение будет работать, но через несколько дней карта перестает отображаться.

Comment: может потому, что Вы используете публичный токен для доступа к их апи? (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/)

Comment: Возможно так. Может он имеет ограниченный период использования

Comment: там написано, что либо нужно брать полноценный токен, либо вручную делать ротацию. то есть, да, ключ "портится" через какое то время.